# (Python) What is wrong in my code causing my program to crash index error

Tags: python, index-error

Program will run the first time through, but in the second loop it will sometimes crash. It was noted to me that it may be in regard to the toppers line, where a topper can be selected.
Error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

```
import random

toppers = ['holographic', 'flakies', 'glitter', 'microshimmer']

def topper():
    while True:
        topper = input() #getting input
        # random number between 1-3 for topper grab
        randomTop = random.randint(1,4)
        if topper.upper() == 'N' or topper.upper() == 'NO':
            print('A clear glossy top coat it is!')
            break
        elif topper.upper() == 'Y' or topper.upper() == 'YES':
            print('The topper you should use is ' + toppers[randomTop] + '.')
            break
        elif topper.upper() != ('N', 'NO', 'Y', 'YES') or topper.isalnum():
            print('\nPlease enter a valid input. Y or N.')
            continue
    playloop()
```

As the program has a break to exit if the user would like, it is expected that the program can loop through endlessly until they are ready to quit. While the first loop works fine, but subsequent trials crash.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
toppers = ['holographic', 'flakies', 'glitter', 'microshimmer']

randomTop = random.randint(1,4)
print('The topper you should use is ' + toppers[randomTop] + '.')
```

`toppers` is a list with four items.  Python lists are indexed starting at zero, so the valid indexes are 0-3.

But you're picking a random number from 1 to 4.  If you happen to pick 4, that is out of range.  Use `random.randint(0,3)`.

Or even better, use `random.choice(toppers)`, so you don't have to worry about the index value at all.

Comment: Ah gosh, thank you. That makes perfect sense. Helped me find another error in my code later with the random numbers in relation to the seasonal colors, I see I had that at (1,8) instead of (0,6) for seven items as well.